# Resize & crop на jQuery

Tags: jquery, javascript, вконтакте, vkontakte-api

Требуется реализовать рейсайзер на jQuery. 
Перебрал все, что только можно. К сожалению, сам не в состояние подобное написать.  Редактировал только то, что имеется.

Я знаю, что таких готовых решений куча, но они меня не устраивают потому что максимальная ширина и высота - статичны. Мне нужны динамичные макс. ширину и макс высоту. (например, как в соц. сети ВК).

допустим максимальная высота = текущая ширина X 2. и т.д

Пытался сам переписать, выходило не то или почти то. но довести до конца не получается. 5-ый день пытаюсь.

Кто-нибудь пытался сделать так же? Можете ли что-то посоветовать? Прошу адекватный ответ, обращаюсь здесь, потому что все перебрал.

Comment: Если все перебрали, но не получилось, то два варианта: 1) перебрали не все; 2) этого сделать нельзя.


Собственно, я к чему: хорошо бы привести "почти то" и указать, что именно не так.

Comment: я не знаю как вы искали, когда по запросу jquery image crop, гугль выдает в первой строчке что-то типа "10 image crop plugins" и первым из них идет этот http://fengyuanchen.github.io/cropper/ (aspect ratio это та опция что вам нужна)

Comment: не совсем то, что нужно. скорее всего виноват я. т.к не правильно объяснил. да, в целом ратио - это то что нужно. но мне нужно динамичное ратио. 
данный ресайзер я видел, давно, он не подошел, вот только не помню почему. и когда его видел, всегда проходил мима. НО, сейчас, после того как Вы предложили его, я решил вновь покататься в нем и переделал все же под свои нужды. Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Я использую этот плагин - [Jcrop](http://deepliquid.com/content/Jcrop.html). В нем можно задавать соотношение сторон.

> Jcrop is the quick and easy way to add image cropping functionality to your web application. It combines the ease-of-use of a typical jQuery plugin with a powerful cross-platform DHTML cropping engine that is faithful to familiar desktop graphics applications.

Answer (score 0):

1. [разбираемся](https://fengyuanchen.github.io/cropperjs/) и [качаем](https://github.com/fengyuanchen/cropperjs) cropper.js
2. После установки/настройки кроппера, необходимо получить картинку и создать экземпляр кроппера с этой картинкой

   `var image = document.getElementById('image');`
   `var cropper = new Cropper(image)`

2.1 Так же, вторым параметром, можно передать json со всем ворохом функций, настроек и событий, как показано в примере:

```
new Cropper(image, {
  ready: function () {
    // this.cropper[method](argument1, , argument2, ..., argumentN);
    this.cropper.move(1, -1);

    // Allows chain composition
    this.cropper.move(1, -1).rotate(45).scale(1, -1);
  }
});
```

3. Необходимо подписаться на событие `crop` или `cropend` в зависимости от того в какой момент Вам нужно будет делать обрезку изображения

   ```
   image.addEventListener('crop', cropImage);
   function cropImage(event) {...}
   ```
4. Тут несколько вариантов развития событий. Первый, вы в `event` получаете параметры **нового** изображения и отправляете **аяксом**, на **бэк**. И на **бэке** делаете обработку изображения и отдаете обратно **аяксом**.
   Второй, вы получаете параметры новой картинки, и, с помощью js, создаете новую картинку. cropImage будет выглядеть примерно так:

   ```
    cropImage(event) {
      cropBoxData = event.getCropBoxData();
      canvasData = event.getCanvasData();

      options.ready = function () {
       cropper.setCropBoxData(cropBoxData).setCanvasData(canvasData);

         sendAjaxFromCanvas();
      };
   ```

   }

   Потом необходимо получить картинку из канваса и отправлять аяксом на бэк:

   ```
   sendAjaxFromCanvas() {
     cropper.getCroppedCanvas().toBlob(function (blob) {
     var formData = new FormData();

     formData.append('croppedImage', blob);
      $.ajax('/path/to/upload', {
        method: "POST",
        data: formData,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function () {
         console.log('Upload success');
        },
        error: function () {
          console.log('Upload error');
        }
      });
    });
   }
   ```